# A photo of an object in an ImageVIew is not displayed

Tags: java, android

I receive an object from another fragment. In that object there is a photo that I can not see in the ImageView. Help?
I have tried changing the string that arrives to me, to bitmap ... but nothing.

````
```@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outfit_today, 
container, false);
imagePartUp = (ImageView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.partUp);
imagePartMiddle = (ImageView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.partMiddle);
imagePartFloor = (ImageView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.partFloor);

for (int i = 0; i <itemsAllPart.size() ; i++) {
itemsPartUp = itemsAllPart.get(0).getImage();
byte[] imageAsBytes = itemsPartUp.getBytes();
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, 
imageAsBytes.length);
imagePartUp.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
return RootView;
}
public void recieveItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
if(itemsAllPart !=null){
        itemsAllPart = items;
}
````

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<String> encode = new ArrayList<>();
String encoded = "";
byte[] byteArray;


for (int i = 0; i < itemsAllPart.size(); i++) 
{
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            itemsAllPart.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, 
            byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            encode.add(encoded);
 }
```

I hope it will work with you